# How to fetch output from console.log

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I have been seeing in some questions on Stack Overflow that there is *examples*, example code or snippets. Such as the one below:

```js
console.log(1, 2, 3)
```

By running the code snippet above you'll see something like this:

[image: console.log output]

I am currently working with something in node.js that also requires to fetch the output from `console.log`s. I find it fascinating that Stack Overflow is able to do this, whilst I don't even have a single clue how they did this.

I would be very thankful if someone could send me a link to where I can read and learn about how to fetch data form the console API.

Cheers,
Richard

P.S. If someone could edit this post to display the image, I'd be very thankful.

**Edit** 
The project that I'm working on is an Electron app. It uses both the node.js process and the Electron BrowserWindow.

It uses a logger that I'm working on wich needs to fetch data from `console.log`

Some of the use cases might look like this:

```
console.log('%d is cool', User.firstName)
// => "Jason is cool"
```

or

```
console.log('User ID:', User._id)
// => A5FFE
```

or

```
console.log('%cUser connected!', 'color: #00FF00')
// => User connected!
// In green text.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite `window.console.log` with your own function to achieve such an effect. For example:

```js
const oldConsoleLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.log = (...params) => {
  const textToDisplay = params.map(param =>
    typeof param === 'object'
    ? JSON.stringify(param)
    : param
  );
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
    .textContent = textToDisplay;
  oldConsoleLog(...params);
};

console.log('foo');
console.log('bar baz');
console.log({ prop: 'value' });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 60%
}
```

Comment: But then again, doing something like `console.log(1, 2, 3)` would only output `1`.

Comment: See edit, you can use `...` to turn all arguments into an array

Comment: Then doing something like `console.log('%d is cool', 'Jason')` would work as well?

Comment: @iHack To replicate all of its functionality you'll have to code to replace `%`s with the other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In nodejs, `console.log` just formats the data you pass to it and then writes it to `process.stdout` which is a stream that goes to your commandline window. To intercept that, you can just listen for events on that stream:

```
process.stdout.on("data", chunk => {
  // Do what you wanna do
});
```

Comment: Though what if the code is executed in for example nw.js or Electron?

Comment: @iHack `I am currently working with something in node.js ` ... I just answered the question you asked ...

Comment: What I'm making needs to be supported in Electron as well, since my app is going to use a special logger both inside of the Electron Browser and the node.js process. Sorry, i'll edit my question.

Comment: Edited my question.